# How can I use RegExp to get value inside and outside the bracket

Tags: javascript

I want to parse data-action in the string below. I've managed to get the data inside it, but I want to parse it so that "action" = togglestate and "params" = anything inside the brackets. I 'm not too good at regex but I'm currently using this with no avail: (This code is in the execaction function)

```
var regex = /(.*)(\((.*)\))?/gi;
var list = elem.dataset.action.match(regex);
var action = list[1];
var params = list.splice(0,2).join();
```

HTML:

`<div data-action='toggleState(test)' onClick='execaction(this);' id='testelem'>div running execaction on click with action parameter</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var action = elem.dataset.action.match(/.*\(/)[0];
if (action != null) action = action.substring(0, action.length - 1);  //remove '('
var params = elem.dataset.action.match(/\(.*/)[0];
if (params != null) {
  params = params.substring(1, params.length -1);  //remove '(' and ')'
  params = params.split(','); //split parameter names
}
```